# "System.OutOfMemoryException" while using ado.net to retrieve 700k records C#

Tags: c#, .net, ado

I fill the data from the table into the list for the first time and then i clear the list to select different data from different table so i want the first list to be released from the memory because i will get new data more and more.

I have tried:

```
List.Dispose(); 
List.Clear();
List = null;
GC.Collect();
```

But the memory keeps full.

in the Entity Framework i figured it out and added the `.AsNoTracking()` and it worked and the memory is cleared

But I have to use ADO.Net.

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: try adding GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() after the collect nmethod

Comment: 700k records in memory...trying to think of...why you need that?

Comment: @Reniuz I wouldn't rule it out; I often work with much much bigger single queries than that - but: I use every trick in my experience to make it work :)

Comment: @MarcGravell I know and agree. I am just trying to question do OP really need to pull out all that data from store. Maybe reducing query result will solve the problem in fist place. Just thinking out of the box...

Answer (score 7):

You can't tell GC what to do. GC releases what GC wants to release. It is usually *very good* at releasing things when you're under memory pressure; if it *can't* release, then I suspect that the objects may still be reachable. In particular, *events* are a very common way that people accidentally keep lots of objects reachable - so you might want to check that you don't have any dangling events.

There *are* ways to try to influence GC, but it is almost always a mistake to do that, and I'm not going to include the voodoo commands here because I think that is not the fix.

ADO.NET **is not** to blame here; EF runs *on top of* ADO.NET. Note that what you *can* do is *avoid lists*; you can read over data as a sequence *without* ever needing it go into a list, but just by working over the reader. Or if you use tools like "dapper" (a very thin helper on top of ADO.NET), you can just use `.Query<T>(...., buffered: false)` (it buffers by default, because usually people aren't reading 700,000 rows).

On the topic of lists: note that large lists hit the "large object heap", which impacts collection more.